# How to copy Tomcat logs to Jenkins & display them after each deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, tomcat7, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins for building & deploying a Java app to Tomcat. I use the [deployer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) plugin to deploy to my Tomcat container. However I have an additional requirement which is - after each deployment I should be able to view the Tomcat log in Jenkins. Is there a way to achieve this? Tomcat & Jenkins are running on different servers.

Comment: OS of the Tomcat server? OS of the Jenkins server?

Comment: @Slav    Both running Ubuntu 14.04 
I used exec shell in Jenkins & ran a script that copies the log to an artifacts folder in Jenkins. I am pretty much happy with this setup.

Comment: Follow the following link:- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280619/how-can-i-configure-jenkins-to-show-my-logs-in-the-workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280619/how-can-i-configure-jenkins-to-show-my-logs-in-the-workspace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On *nix, you can use **Execute Shell** build step to `scp` files from remote machine back Jenkins's `workspace`

`scp login@remote.server:/path/to/catalina.log ${WORKSPACE}/catalina.log`

Once they are in Jenkins workspace, you can just `cat` them to the console log

`cat ${WORKSPACE}/catalina.log`

You could then further archive them as any other artifact from workspace