# Jenkins Logging

Tags: linux, logging, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to automate some tasks on a remote server. During these tasks, a script is creating a lot of log files. How can I make these log files available in Jenkins for other? Jenkins won't be creating these files, some script running on my server will. The job will take ~15 days to complete and I would like users to be able to go take a look at the log files anytime in Jenkins.

Comment: are those stdout logs or external logs?

Comment: No, not stdout logs, only text files I'm creating during the execution.

Comment: sounds like duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280619/how-can-i-configure-jenkins-to-show-my-logs-in-the-workspace)

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a mechanism known as "User Content", where administrators can place files inside $JENKINS_HOME/userContent, and these files are served from http://yourhost/jenkins/userContent. This can be thought of as a mini HTTP server to serve images, stylesheets, and other static resources that you can use from various description fields inside Jenkins.

So just put your log files under the userContent directory, others should see them.